# pl/sql developer IDE

Tags: oracle, ide, plsqldeveloper

I'm using AllRoundAutomatation's Pl/sql developer, and now i'm having quite interesting problem, All I want is to configure CTRL+UP key combination for scoll up!. but I can't manage it, 
How Can I do This ?

Caution: tools > preferences > go to user interface section > key configuration 
that one is not working, cause when I press UP or ctrl+up the  "key configuration"'s table is getting scoll up it self

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools -> Preferences -> user interface section -> key configuration -> scroll down to Editor : scroll up is where you would normally do it, however I see your problem, CTRL+UP is a control key in the preferences window that takes you back up to the top of that window.

If you go to the defaults.ini file on your pl/sql developer install  ( probably in something like C:\Program Files\PLSQL Developer\Preferences\your username ), you can change the entry manually, I'd recommend setting the scroll up entry to someother value, then you will see an entry, you can then change it to 16422, which is the value on my install for CTRL+UP.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows:

```
tools > preferences > go to user interface section > key configuration
```

find item `Editor: Scroll up` select it and press `CTRL+UP` keys combination.

Answer (score 0):

For your information, you may add the following entry to the configuration file to enable CTRL+DOWN to scroll down.

```
Editor: Scroll Down=16424
```